# Basic thenReturn not working in Mockito in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mockito

Sorry for such a basic question. I'm just a little discouraged as to why i can't for the life of me configure a thenReturn on my mock. In eclipse unit test view I'm getting this Failure Trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() request an argument which has to be 'a mthod call on a mock'.
For example:   
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

But here is my code which is really just a simple POJO:

```
ConnectionDetails mockDetails = mock(ConnectionDetails.class);
when(mockDetails.getHostName()).thenReturn("hello");
assertEquals("hello", mockDetails.getHostName());
```

This should work fine no?

Here is failure trace:
[image: eclipse failure trace]

Method declaration:

```
public final String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
}
```

Thanks for pointing out that the issue is the "final" in my method declaration.

Comment: Would you please post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @jean added image of the failure trace, closest thing i have to a stack trace.

Comment: Have you checked that `getHostName` isn't final?

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. Please post your method code.

Comment: You guys were right on. there was a final in the method declaration.

Comment: @Gavin promote to answer?

Comment: @JeffBowman I don't have privileges to do that, should I just add an Answer that says the same thing?

Comment: @Gavin Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant. AFAIK nobody can turn a comment into an answer automatically, including mods.

Comment: Yes Gavin I think you or Jean-Francois should add an answer and the other edit it and I'll mark it. Thank you both again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4187837/gavin) resolved in the comments:

> Have you checked that getHostName isn't final?

Mockito mocks are proxies (effectively dynamically-generated subclasses) and marking methods `final` prevents them from triggering Mockito's overrides. Consequently, your test calls the real method, and Mockito gives a MissingMethodInvocationException.